# Кодировка eclipse + mySQL

Tags: java, glassfish

Добрый день. Такая ситуация, есть проект web app, пишу на java + glassfish, 
есть база данных mySQL, в ней данные, настроил подключение между glassfish и mySQL, делаю запрос из проекта для вывода данных из таблицы в консоль. Получаю след.:

> -2017-07-07T00:02:42.555+0300|Info: ????? ???????

И так для всех записей. Везде, где казалось бы возможным, установил кодировку utf-8. 
Прошу помощи. И так только для русских символов.

Comment: а если в базу посмотреть, то там как?

Comment: А при чём тут Eclipse?